# Increment Row value in excel on each button click

Tags: excel, vba, row, increment

in excel macro I need to increment row each time I click the button. Sort of Next value function that should be read from the datasheet. Also this value needs to be returned to a cell in a different sheet. This is the code I have, how do I increment the value per click. I tried Offset() but I want the button to remember my previous position. Something in For loop maybe

```
Sub Button6_Click()

Cells(4, 6) = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("B:B").Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I've properly understood your question, but it seems you want `Cells(4,6)` to be equal, at each click, to the value of a certain cell in `Sheet4` shifted of one row down. If this is the case:

```
Dim previousRow As Long '<-- global variable previousRow
Sub Button6_Click()
    If previousRow = 0 Then 
        previousRow = 1 '<--starts at row 1
    Else
        previousRow = previousRow + 1 '<--increases of 1 each click
    End If
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4,6) = Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(previousRow,6) '<-- it will be the value of the cell in the column 6 with a variable row
    'first click: Cells(1,6)
    'second click: Cells(2,6)
    'third click: Cells(3,6)
    'etc.
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Matteo thanks a lot. This is exactly what I needed. The button works just fine.